# Accessing one flask route from two different pages in application

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm making a flask application which opens the home page, when a user logs in or when a user completes his/her registration. The problem I'm running into however is that I'm attempting to access the "home" route from the registration page and the home screen, both using "POST" methods.

```
    @app.route("/home", methods=["GET","POST"])
    def login():
        """Logs In"""
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user_name = request.form['username']
            password = request.form['password']

            if check_login(user_name,password,db):
                return render_template("home.html")
        return "These aren't the droids you're looking for"

    def registration():
        """Signs Up"""
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user_name = request.form['username']
            password = request.form['password']

        if register(user_name,password,db):
            return render_template("home.html")
        else:
            return "Not successful"
```

The registration method is called from my newuser.html template and login is called from login.html. Unfortunately, I get an error from newuser.html,
"Could not build url for endpoint 'registration'. Did you mean 'static' instead?."

My guess is that flask does not allow me to have multiple methods under one route. What is a workaround this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reorganize your code to something like that :

```
@app.route("/home", methods=["GET"])
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    """Logs In"""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_name = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        if check_login(user_name,password,db):
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return "These aren't the droids you're looking for"

@app.route("/registration", methods=["POST"])
def registration():
    """Signs Up"""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_name = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

    if register(user_name,password,db):
        return return redirect(url_for('home'))
    else:
        return "Not successful"
```

home() just show your HTML forms (login and registration)

login() + registration() are two different methods with two different route, if the form succeed it redirect to your home page